# XML Array String Item to other Object

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

I have a Spinner where I select a song (item) from a XML String Array like this:

```
<string-array name="lst1">
    <item name="ALittleLessCoanversation" tag="0">A Little Less Conversation
        <game>Just Dance</game>
        <music>A Little Less Conversation</music>
        <artist>Elvis Presley</artist>
    </item>
    .
    .
    .
</string-array>
```

And I want to convert it to a Music object (`new Music(String game, String song, String artist)`).

I tried `spnSongList.getSelectedItem()` and casting to Music:

```
Music music = (Music) spnGameList.getSelectedItem();
```

I also tried to convert it to String and String[], but it always return an error.

What I want is to get that XML Item and convert it to a Music object.

Thanks for those who help.

Comment: You weren't clear enough. Do you want to know how to get an XML file?

Comment: I have an Array in a XML file (like I told, but with much more itens) and I want to convert each item to a Music object and each subitem as atributes of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'xstream' : http://x-stream.github.io/
Its a good and decent library which does exactly what you need.

You can create your own converter to serialize in two ways object <-> xml

http://x-stream.github.io/converters.html

You will have to write an implementation of the Converter class

When you did that all you need to do is

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();

xstream.registerConverter(new MusicConverter());

Music music = (Music)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

Also I suggest you use the builder pattern so that constructing an object looks something like this:

```
Music music =    Music.builder().artist("Elvis").title("A Little Less Conversation").build();
```

Comment: I'll try this, but I'm still a beginner so this solution may take some time. I look for something a bit easier.

Comment: Xstream is about the easiest thing out there. I suggest you take some time to study it and you will find out that it is not that hard